# Help theming hook_theme in Drupal 7

Tags: theming, hooks

I created a module with a hook_theme(). It works fine but when I copy my-custom-template.tpl.php file into my theme folder to customize the override doesn't work. I  don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
function foo_bar_theme() {
  return array(
    'something' => array(
      'template' => 'my-custom-template',
      'variables' => array(
        'zone' => null, 
        'location' => null, 
        'class' => null),
    ),
  );
}
```

Can someone help me please? I've checked everything, cleared the cache, checked the spelling, made sure the names are original to not have name clashes.

Answer (score 1):

The file outside your module should be named (in your example) something.tpl.php.

Comment: This is correct: The template file cannot have a name that is too different from the theme name, apart the difference between hyphens, and underscores. Of course, the template name reported in `hook_theme()` must follow those rules too.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
function foo_bar_theme() {
  return array(
    'something' => array(
      'template' => 'my-custom-template',
      'arguments' => array(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The template name is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your template file must be placed in your modules directory or you can use file option see return values for hook_theme [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

```
function foo_bar_theme() {
  return array(
    'something' => array(
      'template' => 'my-custom-template',
      'file'=>drupal_get_path('theme','my_default_theme').'my_custom_template.tpl.php',

      'variables' => array(
        'zone' => null, 
        'location' => null, 
        'class' => null),
    ),
  );
}
```

you may override theme suggestions in your default theme's template.php you have to write overriding functions like this

function MYTHEME_something($variables){}

you can do this for all theme registry elements(use devel module to see all theme registry)
drupal looks for theme implications like  let's say that you use grayscale theme:

- grayscale_something()
- sites/all/themes/grayscale/something.tpl.php
- theme_something()

the last theme something assumed that you wrote a theme_something function in your module

Comment: The template name (my-custom-template) is not correct when the function name is `theme_something()`.